# Open windows explorer with WPF application directory

Tags: c#

I want to open application directory with button click. i get such error

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: First thought: a folder is not a program.

Comment: If you are trying to open a directory in WIndows explorer, you might want to use Process.Start(explorer.exe,@"/select," + directorypath);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, then you can use `Process` to open a directory. For example, this will open the `C:\` drive. You can specify any path you want.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\";
process.Start();
```

This is similar to using the Run dialog from the start menu. For instance, even though a Word document is not a program, using Shell Execute will allow you to "Start" a word document by using whatever program is associated with it. Likewise the same with a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "explorer.exe {0}" ?  Explorer is the process you want, and the argument your intended path.

Comment: It is possible for some whacko to rename his Explorer.exe to AnythingElse.exe, though...

Comment: It is indeed, but then said wacko is not going to have a  Windows desktop.  Sure, they could run LightStep or something like that as a replacement desktop; but renaming it would also cause problems to their local system.

Comment: Actually, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132422/c-open-folder) suggests that what s/he is trying to do should work. The only difference I see is the \ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [ProcessStartInfo.Verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx) to "Open".