# Is there any way to kill/close/hide a specific explorer window?

Tags: c#

I already read up on the problem, that explorer tasks are behaving a little weird when more then one is opened, because I would have to remove the main explorer window if I wanted do remove a certain one.

I'm currently trying to achieve it like this, but it's obviously not working:

```
private Process explorerProcess = null;

private void startExplorer(){
    explorerProcess = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @*path*);
}

private void closeExplorer(){
    explorerProcess.Kill();
}
```

I also tried .Hide(), .Close() and so on but nothing seems to work. I don't want to loop all explorer processes and end them all, because when I want to get it done smoothly, not by closing all processes and letting the user notice it as soon as I kill the explorer.exe which is responsible for the start menu.

There must be any way I hope...

Comment: _Why_ would you want to kill arbitrary user processes? Can you explain your goal? Why is the code you show "obviously" not working?

Comment: I would not suggest killing explorer.exe. Have you tried `Process.CloseMainWindow()` ?

Comment: I don't want to kill that process. I want to open up a windows explorer instance for my users to browse and paste a file, and as soon as a button is pressed I want to close it again

Comment: @CodeCaster because he is the one creating it

Comment: And you can't use a SaveFileDialog or something?

Comment: You're confusing processes and windows, these are different concepts. Try looping through all windows (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855828/get-process-handle-of-windows-explorer) and if you can find a way to idenfify which is yours, close only that window, by handle.