# Access is denied exception when using Process.Start() to open folder

Tags: c#, winforms, process.start, win32exception

I have a winforms application in C# where I have to open a certain Folder.
I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToFolder);
```

This results in the following exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>
> at MyApp.openLogFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I have already checked the following things:

- The folder exists
- The user has rights to the folder (can open it in Explorer)

Another thing is that if I use `Process.Start()` to open a file inside this folder, it works.

Can anyone give me a hint?
Cheers

**Edit**
My goal is to open the folder in Explorer.
The `pathToFolder` is something like `H:\Something\App.Name\Log`

Comment: Not sure what most folks commenting & answering are talking about when they reiterate that Process.Start won't open a folder path. It does. I work on a .NET Framework app that has used this feature for years. I'm here because I just migrated the app to .NET Core, and now I'm getting the "access is denied" error.

Comment: @William Confirming. The problem is not present in .NET Framework where Process.Start(directory) is sufficient. But it yields the error in .NET Core.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Doc's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-string)) the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string)` runs the file or process (and therefore does not open the folder). For opening a folder, [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-string-system-string)) sugests that you might do this with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string, string)` where first should be a way to explorer, Total commander or something similar, and second should be a argument telling the used explorer what to do (open the folder `pathToFolder`).

I suppose that some system variable stores the value for "default folder viewer" but I do not know where. I will try to go for it and return later with the answer.

Hope that it helps.

---

**EDIT:** I did some quick digging around and to open the folder the following should do the trick:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") +
    @"\explorer.exe", pathToFolder);
```

Where first argument is a path to classical windows explorer and second is the actual path to the folder itself.
It seem that widows does not by itself hold path to other "folder viewer" (such as Total Commander etc.), so this way is probably off the table.

Comment: Could solve the problem by simply calling `Process.Start("explorer.exe", pathToFolder);` instead of `Process.Start(pathToFolder);`

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = pathToFolder,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: This is the best way! One reason for that is that if you call this multiple times, it wont reopen the folder multiple times and will reuse the original window

Comment: This works well when opening directories that require elevated permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this to open file/directory:

```
    public static void OpenFile(string path, bool isDirectory = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return;
        if ((isDirectory && Directory.Exists(path)) || (!isDirectory && File.Exists(path)))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
            pi.Arguments = Path.GetFileName(path);
            pi.UseShellExecute = true;
            pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            pi.Verb = "OPEN";

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = pi;

            proc.Start();
        }
    }
```

or

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe",path);
```

If this doesn't work it may be a permission issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the working directory like this but you can't run the directory itself only files or exe

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = //working directory 
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score -2):

This error actually happens when there is a difference between the default behaviour of opening the file and the relative behaviour of opening the file.
For example, if you have selected the default application to open .pdf files as  Internet Explorer, and you are trying to open the same file using Process.Start() method. You will receive an exception because as per the default operations it should open that file in Internet Explorer and your application is trying to open it using Adobe reader.

To rectify this set the default application for the .pdf file as Adobe Reader and you won't receive this error any more. 
You can do this by, right-clicking on the file and then select, Default program or App. Further, select the default Program or App from the list of available programs and then select the Always use the selected program/App to open files of this type.

Comment: That's not true. Nothing keeps you from opening a file with a different program than the one that is chosen as the default under Windows. Imagine what would happen if there were a ".TXT file monopoly" on your PC!