# how to open a folder by clicking a button in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

### How to open a folder by clicking a button in windows form application

I am developing a project in **windows form application** where I have created PDF file.By clicking a button, I want to open the folder of PDF file where  I have saved it.
so how can I do this?

N.B: I don't want to run any .exe file. I only want to open a folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132422/open-a-folder-using-process-start

Comment: If you got your answer then mark it as Accepted answer.

Comment: _I don't want to run any process. I only want to open a folder._ This is nonsense. Folders must be opened by some process. It makes no sense otherwise. Maybe you mean the FolderBrowserDialog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one should work

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("c:\\");
```

it opens the c drive in explorer for you

Comment: if this solved your issue than accept this as answer