# Open a folder using Process.Start for specific folder

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Hi I searched the web and found the example [Open a folder using Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132422/open-a-folder-using-process-start) to open the folder. I followed it and created a console app but the folder is  opened my document folder instead of my input folder. For my testing, I executed it in cmd prompt by typing "\sharefuser01\users$\tester\2012". It opened the "\sharefuser01\users$" folder.  Would someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
           Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(args(0))
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", args(0))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("directory path")
```

or

```
Dim Proc As String = "Explorer.exe"

Dim Args As String =
   ControlChars.Quote &
   IO.Path.Combine("C:\", "Folder with spaces in the name") &
   ControlChars.Quote

Process.Start(Proc, Args)
```